# Verify if image link is really a image link before updating it to database

Tags: php

how do we verify image link if its really a image link using php?

I have a website where user can save image link but i want to check that link before adding it to database, And i only want to accept jpg and png file type.

SUPPOSE: `http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/65952_491770220880511_1455944784_n.jpg`

How to verify it?

Just want to know if there is a way :)

Thanks in advance

**thanks all for helping**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHPs function [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) to check the content-type of the file.

You can fake headers though (e.g. with PHPs header() function), but  for a basic verification, this should work.

```
$headers = get_headers("http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/65952_491770220880511_1455944784_n.jpg", 1);
if ($headers["Content-Type"] == "image/png" or $headers["Content-Type"] == "image/jpeg") {
    // It is a PNG or JPG
}
```

Also, it could be (but I'm not entirely sure) that the server returns variations of the Content-Type like "image/jpg" or "img/png". You have to play around with it until you cover all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You could try retrieving the picture with CURL and check the headers to see the Content-Type. If it's matching with a picture, you could either copy the picture with imageMagick or just save the link into your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the headers only to see the **Content-Type**,which can assure you only type of file not for existence or error free file.I am also eager to know that is it possible to verify(existence) a URL or image url ?

Comment: Well for me i dont care about if file is really exist, i just care only about its header :)